# Missed out on becoming a vampire lord, can I still become one?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I never became a vampire lord, killed Harkon I think his name was, and cured Serana. Is there anyway I can become a vampire lord?

I'm playing on the Xbox 360.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The cases in the two questions are different. In this question, OP has already killed Harkon and has cured Serana, while in the other, that hasn't happened yet and the OP is asking about what will happen if they chose to join the Dawnguard.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have defeated Lord Harkon and cured Serana of vampirism, there is no way to become a Vampire Lord (outside of PC-only console commands).

Comment: If the answer has helped you, consider marking this question as the accepted one

Comment: technically you can try disabling and reenabling the DLC